# How to use 'from workspace' as output of if/else block in Simulink

Tags: simulink

Modeling a wet well for a sewage pump. Using a relay to activate the pump when the water level reaches a certain height. If/else block pertains to the fact that if the incoming flow rate (from workspace) at which the pump activation occurs is less than 300gpm, then the pump turns on at 300gpm regardless. Otherwise, the pump turns on at the incoming flow rate.  This output from the if/else block is really just the input from the previous step (from workspace). How do I link a 'from workspace' output to the if/else block?

Comment: Don't you just need a From Workspace connected to the 1st input of a "max" block and a constant (=300) into the 2nd input of the block?

Comment: Thanks, Phil. The problem is, the incoming flowrate from the workspace is (originally) unaltered. Only when the pump is activated (after the relay determines if the water height is adequate), does the if/else statement apply. In other words, the incoming flowrate during any timestep could be unchanged, but the outgoing flowrate is forced to 300 gpm so that the tank is emptying while on.

Comment: (I think) I'd still just use a Switch block -- make the control signal an indication of whether the pump is on or off, the flow rate being one potential output signal and a constant of 300 the other.

Comment: I used a combination of switch blocks -- thanks Phil!